# How to join lists according to an index and combine member if index already exist

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have 3 different lists containing objects. Every object has several members/variables and one of them serves as a special identifier (index). I would like to join those 3 lists and if there are objects that have the same identifier then those 2 listelements should be combined to one listelement

```
List1
id= 1, name= x, value= 10
id= 2, name= tz, value= 10

List2
id= 2, name= y, value= 11

List3
id= 3, name=z, value= 12
id= 4, name hh, value= 16

final List
id= 1, name= x, value= 10
id= 2, name= tz, value= 10, name= y, value= 11
id= 3, name=z, value= 12
id= 4, name hh, value= 16
```

I have some experience with lambda Expressions and LINQ, but I could not solve the problem.

Comment: Please post some code. You generally should have code for any question tagged with any code tag. Specifically showing how lists are populated, and whether they contain objects of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

You could concatenate the lists and group by the id, assuming that the lists contain items of the same type.

```
var newList = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).GroupBy(x => x.id).ToList();
```

This will give you a list of  `IGrouping` objects where the `Key` of each `IGrouping` is your id and the `IGrouping` object is an `IEnumerable` of the type in your original lists.

```
foreach(var group in newList)
{
    var id = group.Key;
    Console.Write("id=" + id)
    foreach(var item in group)
    {
        Console.Write(", name=" + item.name + ", value=" + item.value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first group the items by ID (same as @juharr's answer) and I'd suggest to further project the result into an IEnumerable (`groupedById`) where each item has an `id` property and a property called `itemsWithId` which in turn is an `IEnumerable<YourOriginalItemType>`.

```
List<item> l1 = new List<item>() { new item { id = 1, name = "John", value = "Smith" }, new item { id = 2, name = "James", value = "Jackson" } };
List<item> l2 = new List<item>() { new item { id = 2, name = "Jean", value = "Smith" }, new item { id = 3, name = "Bob", value = "Roberts" } };

var groupedById = l1.Concat(l2).GroupBy(i => i.id).Select(grp => new { id = grp.Key, itemsWithId = grp });

//usage:
foreach (var group in groupedById)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ItemId: " + group.id);
    foreach (var item in group.itemsWithId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tName: " + item.name + ", Value: " + item.value);                    
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ItemId: 1
        Name: John, Value: Smith
ItemId: 2
        Name: James, Value: Jackson
        Name: Jean, Value: Smith
ItemId: 3
        Name: Bob, Value: Roberts
```